# Unknown clipping around Border

Tags: silverlight

I have a `Grid` layout. In one row, I have a `Border` and inside it a `ToggleButton`(with negative left margin so that it appears half outside the border). I've added `DropShadowEffect` to the border. Something seems to be clipping the shadow effect and the togglebutton outside the border. Please refer to the code and the image below.

```
 <Grid Margin="0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="140*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="500"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Background="LightGray">
            <Border Background="{StaticResource BorderFill}" Height="150" Width="400" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="20,0,20,10" BorderBrush="#FF999999" BorderThickness="1">
                <Border.Effect>
                    <DropShadowEffect Color="Gray" BlurRadius="40" ShadowDepth="0.1"/>
                </Border.Effect>
                <ToggleButton Click="MenuToggleButtonClick" Margin="-6.5,0,0,5" Style="{StaticResource ExpandCollapseButtons}" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" x:Name="MenuToggleButton" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
            </Border>
        </Grid>
```

[image: clipping of shadow and button]

The left red arrow shows where the button is getting clipped and the right red arrow shows where the dropshadow is getting clipped. What is going on? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that this clipping only occurs when there isn't enough space for the inner `Grid` plus its margin.  I was able to reproduce the behaviour in your screenshot if I resized the browser window small enough.

In your case, it appears there isn't enough height.  A similar effect happens if there isn't enough width.

I'm not sure why this border clipping is happening. However, I found that if
I added the attributes `MinWidth="440"` and `MinHeight="160"` (the width and height of the inner grid plus its margin) to the outer `Grid`, I could no longer reproduce the clipping no matter how small I resized the browser window in any direction.

Comment: What If I cant give the grid row the entire space and need for part of it to be hidden?

Comment: @Aks: you could try wrapping the outer `Grid` in another Grid, perhaps?